# Primary key is foreign keyed to itself in a credible reference manual - How can this work?

Tags: sql, recursion, foreign-keys, recursive-query

I have a DB schema from [The Data Model Resource Book, Vol. 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471380237). In it is a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AccountingPeriod](
  [AccountingPeriodID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [RoleTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [PeriodTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
  [AcctgPeriodNum] [int] NOT NULL,
  [FromDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
  [ThruDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
  [PartyID] [int] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
  [AccountingPeriodID] ASC)
```

With a constraint defined as:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AccountingPeriod]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([AccountingPeriodID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AccountingPeriod] ([AccountingPeriodID])
```

The AccountingPeriodID column has a self referencing foreign key that the text claims is a recursive reference column but I think it's an error. I think I need another column to properly store recursive references in this table. Can the author's method be implemented with the table definition supplied, why?

Comment: As you describe it, I would agree with you.  A foreign key reference would be something like `Prev_AccountingPeriodId` to get to the previous period.

Comment: The idea behind the constraint is to allow the table to establish a hierarchy of AccountingPeriods, (i.e. 4 calendar quarters have a parent that is a calendar year, implemented in 5 total rows).

Comment: I agree with you and @Gordon -- something like `Prev_AccountingPeriodID int NULL` so that records without a parent record won't require a value in the new column.

Comment: @JamesL - I've done the task as you describe it many times. However, I've been questioning my method this time around b/c the book had so many well thought out storage models that I figured I must be missing something in his explanation.

Comment: I've been designing databases for 15+ years and have never seen a primary key reference itself as a foreign key.  As such a record could only reference itself; no parent/child relationships are possible.  I see no value in a record recursively referencing itself.  I vote that it is a typo.

Comment: FWIW - I created the table and foreign key as described in SQL Server 2008 R2, and it let me do it, and insert rows, and retrieve the rows.  So, yes, it does work.  But I still fail to see the value.

Comment: I posted the question to the books author and he replied that his intent was for the recursion to use two columns. So that solves my question in practice. A small omission in an otherwise fantastic book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You need another column which will reference the primary key column of the table itself, for self referencing a table. **Self referencing column really does not make any sense.**

Comment: Sazzadur - I already know what I think and I'm glad you agree with me. However, what I'm looking for is for someone to post technical explanation of how the book's method is flawed.